# Fedora 18 add new hard disk with LVM Partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, fedora, lvm

I recently built my 1st computer and realized today that despite having multiple hard disks, I'm out of space because I did not set up the partitions correctly.

I am trying to add two of my hard disks (not the boot disk) to my LVM group.

First I made LVM partitions in my two drives following the example here:
http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_18&p=add_hd

Now, the output of `fdisk -l` shows me:

```
[root@localhost lvm]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1d04f8ff

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000988f9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2         1026048   500117503   249545728   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000081

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          63   976768064   488384001   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa2da0487

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 8338 MB, 8338276352 bytes, 16285696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 193.5 GB, 193508409344 bytes, 377946112 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Now, to add the new created partitions to the LVM group, I was following the instructions provided here:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Adding_a_New_Disk_to_a_Fedora_Volume_Group_and_Logical_Volume
I should run `pvcreate sda` which gives me:

```
[root@localhost namu]# pvcreate /dev/sda
  Device /dev/sda not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

In `\etc\lvm\lvm.conf`, I have the filter set to

```
filter = [ "a/.*/" ]
```

I deleted `/etc/lvm/cache` and rebooted my system but `pvcreate sda` still returns the same message.

I ran the set of commands below to see if my computer is properly detecting these partitions:

```
[root@localhost namu]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
[root@localhost namu]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sdb2   VG fedora   lvm2 [237.98 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [237.98 GiB] / in use: 1 [237.98 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
[root@localhost namu]#  lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/fedora/swap' [7.77 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/fedora/home' [180.22 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/fedora/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
```

and it does not seem to be. Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out at last.

The problem is that by changing the format of my drive to LVM, I am actually creating a partition of my hard disk (which is almost the entire hard disk). The partition is /dev/sda1. Therefore, I have to use the command

`pvcreate /dev/sda1`

In case anyone in the future has trouble with adding a hard disk into an existing LVM group, I recommend following instructions on

http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_18&p=add_hd

to create an LVM partition and then

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Adding_a_New_Disk_to_a_Fedora_Volume_Group_and_Logical_Volume

to add this new partition to the volume group.