# Fedora 17 - Add 3rd harddrive to /home

Tags: partitioning, fedora, formatting

I'm running Fedora 17 64bit that have 320gb and 500gb hard drive.

Command `df -h` shows that `/dev/mapper/centos-home` has size of 710G.

I want to add third hard drive and increase size of `/dev/mapper/centos-home`

Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Fedora 17 is years after EOL and does not receive any security updates. You should update to something more recent (there is Fedora 24 in the door).

Comment: There are a number of additional questions which cover this, like [Fedora 18 add new hard disk with LVM Partition](http://superuser.com/questions/588535/fedora-18-add-new-hard-disk-with-lvm-partitiond), and while Jakuje is absolutely right, the basic here haven't changed. But one thing to be aware of is that by just adding another drive to an existing VG without any redundancy, you are significantly increasing your risk of catastrophic data loss.